# Solve the given initial value problem

Tags: calculus

Solve the given initial value problem for $y=f(x)$.

$dy/dx = e^{-x}$  where $y=-16$ when $x=0$

$y(x)=$_____

Comment: Integrate, use the initial condition to evaluate the constant of integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x) = -e^{-x} +C$. Thus, $-16 = - e^0 + C \Rightarrow f(x) = -e^{-x} -15$.